# about the lua version installed on armbian , it seems confusing

Tags: lua, luasocket, lua-5.1, armbian

The armbian img is  "Armbian_23.05.0_amlogic_s905l3a_bullseye_5.15.110_server_2023.05.02"

I want use luasocket, but it is not support lua 5.4, so lua 5.1 was installed, however......

Which lua version installed? i want lua 5.1 only, and what can i do?

[dpkg -l](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHX9N.png)

[lua -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUu5l.png)

[remove lua5.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b78v3.png)

[which lua](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRayL.png)

[install lua5.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBxuM.png)

Comment: Does `lua5.1 -v` do something?

Comment: armbian:~:% lua5.1 -v
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio

Comment: You have Lua 5.1 installed in `/usr/bin` (???) and Lua 5.4 in `/usr/local/bin`.  They can happily live separately in different folders.   Just create symbolic links to both of them for your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Lua 5.1 is installed. You can use the `lua5.1` command to run it.

You can also use `update-alternatives --config lua-interpreter` (and similar for `lua-compiler`) to choose which version should run when you use the `lua` command without a version number.